# Check if a string is composed by several substrings from a whitelist Table

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Is there any way to select the expected records with Access query or SQL?

#### Environment

Access 2010

#### Table "words"

actual number of records: ten thousands-order

```
id | word          |
---|---------------|
1  | green         |
2  | light         |
3  | greenlight    |
4  | redlight      |
5  | greenLEDlight |
6  | reddiamond    |
```

#### Table "whitelist"

actual number of records: thousands-order

```
listword |
-------- |
green    |
light    |
```

#### Expected result

1) Select the following, with excluding "word" which consists of only "listword" including ones with concatenating them(*)

```
id | word          |
---|---------------|
4  | redlight      |
5  | greenLEDlight |
6  | reddiamond    |
```

2) Or, select only "word" which of only "listword" including ones with concatenating them(*)

```
id | word          |
---|---------------|
1  | green         |
2  | light         |
3  | greenlight    |
```

(*) "green" or "light" or "greenlight" or "lightgreen"

#### What I tried

```
SELECT words.id, words.word
FROM words, whitelist
WHERE not exists (
    SELECT listword
    FROM whitelist
    WHERE word Like "*" & [listword] & "*"
    )
GROUP BY words.id, words.word;
```

#### Result

```
id | word          |
---|---------------|
6  | reddiamond    |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do these two queries return what you look for ?

1)

```
SELECT id, word
FROM words
WHERE not exists (
    SELECT *
    FROM whitelist
    WHERE listword = word
    )
    and not exists (
    SELECT *
    FROM whitelist w1, whitelist w2
    WHERE w1.listword & w2.listword = word
    )
```

2)

```
SELECT id, word
FROM words
WHERE exists (
    SELECT *
    FROM whitelist
    WHERE listword = word
    )
    or exists (
    SELECT *
    from whitelist w1, whitelist w2
    WHERE w1.listword & w2.listword = word
    )
```

This code will check simple words on the whitelist and the existence of "exact" pairs like "greenlight". But will fail if you also need to check triplets like "greenlightgreen". You can add new subqueries crossing three or more times the whitelist table, but having thousands of records it will be awfully slow.

Comment: Thanks Marc, that's the point. Returning "greenlight" is also expected. I edited "Expected result" part. Sorry for misunderstanding by my English.

Comment: Now reading your edited post I see what you meant. This query will be difficult, having thousands of listwords on the whitelist, there are millions of possible combinations. On SQL Server I would probably try a recursive stored procedure, but on Access / simple SQL I don't see how is possible.

Comment: I have modified my proposal so now it will also recognize "greenlight". It will take quite some time because they are thousands X thousands = millions of possibilities to check.

Comment: I appreciate your detail answer, the two queries worked as expected. I agree and understand more and more possibilities should be checked for multiplets ("greengreenlightgreen" etc.)